# JavaScript data grid in a fluid layout?

Tags: javascript, css, datagrid, dojo, fluid-layout

We are contemplating using the [DataGrid component from DojoX](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/grid) in our web applications. The problem I have is that it doesn't seem to play well with fluid (a.k.a. liquid) CSS layouts -- it seems to like every width predefined. In fact [the documentation](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/grid/DataGrid#auto-width-columns) warns about the automatic width for the columns feature and my attempts to use dynamic width and height for the table itself failed.

Does anyone use this component with a fluid layout? Any other JavaScript data grid components that do a better job (we will need pagination and cell editing would be nice)?

Or is this problem too hard to solve in the context of JavaScript and CSS rendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [dojo.layout.BorderContainer](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/layout/BorderContainer) for layout, and place my DataGrid(s) within the ContentPane(s) of the BorderContainer. The grid is set to 100% for width and height and it automatically adjusts to the height/width of the ContentPane it's placed in. Your basic BorderContainer has 5 regions, but you can embed a BorderContainer within a BorderContainer for more complex layouts.